# NullPointer in Glassfish when inject JMS @Resource

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms

I'm trying to write a very simple JMS app to deploy on Glassfish as a means of getting my head around JMS.

In the class the sends the message I have the following:

```
    @Resource(mappedName="jms/MyConnectionFactory")
    public static QueueConnectionFactory factory;

    @Resource(mappedName="jms/MyQueue")
    public static Queue queue;
```

This results in a NullPointer, the first time I try and access the factory.  If I try and look up the object using JNDI, however, it works. This class is simply a POJO which is accessed by a JSP running in a simple web app.

Is it because it is a POJO and not, for example, a servlet that this is failing?

I had assumed that the fact it was deployed and running inside Glassfish would be enough - obviously I am wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `name` instead of `mappedName`. `name` is the JNDI name, `mappedName` is something else. See [the API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html)

```
@Resource(name="jms/MyConnectionFactory")
public static QueueConnectionFactory factory;
```

I just read that your class is a simple POJO. Your class must be some bean that is managed by a container in order to make these annotations work. Like @Stateless, @Stateful, @Singleton.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into the @Singleton annotation.

Comment: Had exact same issue in Glassfish 3 and 4. Changing to name solved the problem, thanks.