# How do I inject a JMS resource in a JAX-RS REST Web Service?

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, jax-rs, java-ee-6

Using GlassFish 3.1.2.1, I have configured a JMS connection factory and a queue, which can be injected in JavaServer Faces managed beans using the @Resource annotation.

However when I try to use these JMS resources in a JAX-RS REST web service in the same project, the connectionFactory injection seems to be missing and there is a NullPointerException when the line is executed:

```
connection = exampleQueueFactory.createConnection();
```

The injection code is

```
@Resource(mappedName = "ExampleQueue")
private Queue exampleQueue;
@Resource(mappedName = "ExampleQueueFactory")
private ConnectionFactory exampleQueueFactory;
```

and as I successfully use the same injection in JSF managed beans I guess that the GlassFish server skips the JAX-RS classes when looking for injection points. Is there additional configuration missing?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152062/nullpointer-in-glassfish-when-inject-jms-resource

Comment: You current solution is a crutch but *should* work until JAX-RS 2.0 is finalized and proper integration between JAX-RS and CDI is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer to [NullPointer in Glassfish when inject JMS @Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152062/nullpointer-in-glassfish-when-inject-jms-resource) I added a `@javax.ejb.Stateless` annotation and it works.

Follow-up question: is this the recommended way to enable injection of JMS resources in a JAX-RS resource class?

Comment: In order to properly separate your code, I wouldn't recommend it.  In order to activate any injection - CDI or EJB, you need your JAX-RS endpoint to be a CDI or EJB component.  You could also give it CDI's @RequestScoped to enable.